# What day of the week I am?

Tags: mathematics, time

I am the day of the week that wants to be the first day of a year that is a perfect power. I do not like odd years. In order to be a perfect power, the year must **end one day of the week later than the year started**. Otherwise, I can never be the day of the week of the first day of a year that is a perfect power. What day I am?

Hints:

> Years that are perfect powers are the years that can be written as $a^{b}$, where $b\geq2$. Examples are next year, $2116$, and $2197$.

> The bold sentence means that the year must be a leap year.

Comment: By "perfect power" do you mean $a^b$ where a, b integer and $b \ge 2$ ?  I mean, besides the "ends one day later" condition?

Comment: Yes. I do mean” if the year starts on Thursday, then that year will end on Friday.

Comment: Then why "power".

Comment: I mean a year that is a perfect power. For example, $2197$.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that I have the correct interpretation, this question doesn't have a fixed answer, but below I have worked out what I can.

> I want to be the first day of the week of a perfect power year. I do not like odd years.

> Even perfect powers are multiples of 4, because they consist of an even base raised to a power of at least 2.

> In order to be perfect, the year must end one day later than it started.

> This only happens when a year has 365 days, so the year must be a multiple of 4 that is *not* a leap year. These are the years that are multiples of 100 but not 400.
>  This restricts the possible perfect powers tremendously. 400 divides 10000, so  perfect powers can only be squares and cubes, and furthermore they must be the squares and cubes of ten times odd numbers.

> All odd squares are congruent to 1 modulo 8, so let's check those first.
>  How many days are in 800 years? There's 365×800, plus 200 potential leap days, minus 6 missing leap days from years divisible by 100 but not 400, which yields 292194 = 41742×7. Therefore, all the years derived from odd squares will have their first days fall on the same day of the week, which any of several online utilities will tell you is a **Friday**.

> For the years derived from cubes, we have no such luxury. 41742 is divisible by 2, but not by 4, so the cubes congruent to 1 modulo 4 are covered by the above argument, but not the ones congruent to 3 modulo 4, which lead to years like 27000 that begin on **Wednesday**.

The existence of this second case is likely what breaks the question.

Comment: January 1 and December 31 fall on the same day of the week in common years. The year must be a leap year for it to end one day of the week later than it started.

Comment: Of course, that doesn't make the question any more tractable.

Comment: I think it was meant to be restricted to non-leap years.  Assuming that and considering that our calendar didn't exist before 1500 and will probably be replaced before 27000, makes the answer reasonably well defined.